# Remove duplicate from result ElasticSearch via Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, distinct, dsl

I  run this query

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'127.0.0.1' , 'port' : 1234}])
query = '{ "query": { "match" : { "name" : {"query ": "Jone" , "type" : "phrase" }}}}'
es.search(index='MyIndex' , q=query , size =50)
```

to get all documents where `name = Jone`

What I want is to remove duplicate result by 2 columns for example `city` and `country` by `@timestamp`. So if there are 4 "Jone"s in the same city **and** same  country, I will see only the last item that insert by @timestamp.

I want to do that in ElasticSearch side , not to get all data and filter it with python.

How to do that?